# How to display database records in asp.net mvc view using DB2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, db2

Using ASP.NET MVC with C#, Is there a basic reference that I can start up on creating connection string for DB2 in controller then loads it to my view. I just currently referring to this link but the only difference is I need DB2 rather than SQL.

1.Model

```
public class Student
{
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public string Class {get;set;}
    ....
}
```

2. Controller

   ```
    public ActionResult Students()
    {
    String connectionString = "<THE CONNECTION STRING HERE>";
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM students";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

   var model = new List<Student>();
   using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
   {
       conn.Open();
       SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
       while(rdr.Read())
       {
           var student = new Student();
           student.FirstName = rdr["FirstName"];
           student.LastName = rdr["LastName"];
           student.Class = rdr["Class"];
           ....

           model.Add(student);
       }

   }

   return View(model);
   ```

   }

will appreciate your suggestions and comments.

Comment: replace the data retrieval from sql server with that from DB2. the rest remains the same

Comment: I tried to substitute those sql to DB2Command by importing IBM.Data.DB2 but there still missing that cannot be read, could you give me sample reference?